# java.sql - ResultSet r.next() doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I don't understand why ResultSet isn't working as if there are no results

```
public static int checkProductID(Connection conn) {

    boolean productIDisvalid = false;
    int id = 0;
    while (!productIDisvalid) {
        System.out.println("Enter a product ID: ");
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(readLine());
            if (id < 10000000 && id > 0) {
                System.out.println(id);
                // PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO INVENTORY VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
                // pstmt.setInt(1,4000); pstmt.setString(2,"hello"); pstmt.setInt(3,4000); pstmt.setInt(4,400);
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE PRODUCTID = ?");
                pstmt.setInt(1, id);
                ResultSet r = pstmt.executeQuery();
                while (r.next()) {
                    System.out.println(r.getInt("PRODUCTID"));
                    if (r.getInt("PRODUCTID") == id) return id;
                }
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException | SQLException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

I quoted out an insert values to prove it works and that it is correctly connected to the database.

[image]

The insert values works. But whenever I attempt to perform a search query on the database, it doesn't work, r.next() is never true and the print statement inside that while loop never executes, even if I change the query to "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE PRODUCTID = 1000"

Comment: I don't know if there's enough information here for us to help. What happens if you add a semicolon `;` to the end of the query? What happens if you wrap the `?` in apostrophes `'?';`?

Comment: @JacobG. I just changed it to "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY" and it prints 4000 once but not 1000, 2000, 3000 as it should when it cycles through (it should actually just be printing 1000 as the search id used was 1000, and then returning, very strange. Adding ; causes a syntax error btw, this is the correct format

Comment: "Adding ; causes a syntax error" - I find that hard to believe. Are you adding it in the correct location? And if you're seeing values that you don't expect, then your table probably contains other data.

Comment: @JacobG. It's true that adding ";" causes a syntax error, it's something I tried logically. I've just worked it out but it's beyond me, it works if i use the id 4000 and returns correctly. It's as if it thinks the table begins at id 4000, it's only recognising entries entered by the program itself and not the schema.sql batch file that entered some preliminary entries, even though they are indeed in the table.

Comment: Ok, ridiculous, it works now, just terminated the ssh connection and restarted it. Now recognises those entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was happening because you had not explicitly committed your insert from sqlplus. When you exit sqlplus there is an implicit commit that happens which is why the problem went away.